# Reduce CPU utilization when condition is false

Tags: c#, optimization, while-loop, time-complexity, cpu-usage

I'm developing an application that runs every day in a particular time, I used while loop inside when inside while loop condition is false CPU take much time and resource to process, how I reduce CPU utilization when inside the loop condition false.

```
while (true)    // run everyday without stop
{
    IntPtr hwnd;                           // hide command prompt file
    hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();            // 
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);            //
    
    TimeSpan startMor= new TimeSpan(int.Parse(SHP1), int.Parse(SMP1), 0);     // set the hours and minutes 
    TimeSpan endMor = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(EHP1), int.Parse(EMP1), 0);      // 
    TimeSpan startEve = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(SHP2), int.Parse(SMP2), 0);   //
    TimeSpan endEve = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(EHP2), int.Parse(EMP2), 0);     //
    TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;          // current time of day
    var hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;                    // current hours,  set to check 
    var minutes = DateTime.Now.Minute;               // current minutes, set to check

    // hour to minutes conversion 
    int minutesProcess1 = ((int.Parse(EHP1) - (int)hour) * 60) + int.Parse(EMP1) - (int)minutes;       // process 1 conversion 
    int minutesProcess2 = ((int.Parse(EHP2) - (int)hour) * 60) + int.Parse(EMP2) - (int)minutes;      // process 2 conversion

    //int time_to_process = 1;

    if ((now >= startMor) && (now < endMor))
    {
       // var process1 = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
        var process1 = Process.Start(path_1);
        Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 1 * minutesProcess1);                
        //process.WaitForExit(10000);
        process1.Kill();
    } 
    else if((now >= startEve) && (now < endEve))
    {
        var process2 = Process.Start(path_2);
       // var process2 = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
        Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 1 * minutesProcess2);
        //process.WaitForExit(1000);
        process2.Kill();
    }
}
```

Comment: Simplest would be to add an `else` and a `Thread.Sleep()` so it doesn't poll continuously thrashing the CPU, but really you should be using some other form of scheduled task to run this not a busy loop. Take a look at `Windows Task Scheduler` or `Quartz.net`.

Comment: Why not just use _Windows Task Scheduler?_  Though COM-based, it's nice object model is easy to use from managed apps.  Just add a _COM-reference_

Comment: There are Timer classes with the express purpose of doing things regularly.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There are: [Windows Task Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/using-the-task-scheduler), [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/), [QuartzNET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), [Timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/timers)...

Comment: Actually, I did not know that library.